# SQL Select with a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, select, sql-server-2000

I have the following SQL Statement :

```
SELECT 
   RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(LAGKART.VARENUMMER,CHAR(2),'')))                 AS ItemNo,
   RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(LAGKART.SXSON,CHAR(2),'')))                          AS Season, 
   ISNULL(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(LAGKART.VARIANT1,CHAR(2),''))),'')            AS Variant1, 
   ISNULL(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(LAGKART.VARIANT2,CHAR(2),''))),'')            AS Variant2,
   (SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[B2BGetSpringFinal] ( LAGKART.VARENUMMER, 
                                    LAGKART.VARIANT1,
                                    LAGKART.VARIANT2
                                  )) AS SpringAvailable
FROM 
   LAGKART
```

But I get this error :

> Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'.

But if I call the function with fixed values :

```
SELECT 
   RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(LAGKART.VARENUMMER,CHAR(2),'')))                 AS ItemNo,
   RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(LAGKART.SXSON,CHAR(2),'')))                          AS Season, 
   ISNULL(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(LAGKART.VARIANT1,CHAR(2),''))),'')            AS Variant1, 
   ISNULL(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(LAGKART.VARIANT2,CHAR(2),''))),'')            AS Variant2,
   (SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[B2BGetSpringFinal] ( '6261', 
                                     'Black',
                                     'S'
                                   )) AS SpringAvailable
FROM 
   LAGKART
```

I get the desired result.

Any ideas?

Br
Mads

Comment: what dialect is that? TSQL?  it looks kind of whacky but not nuts enough to bt mysql.  anway I'm pretty sure you can't pull result columns into subselects like that.either maybe you want a CTE?

Comment: It's T-SQL
Think your are right that i can't use result columns in subselects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2000, Only constants and @local_variables can be passed to table-valued functions. In SQL 2005 and greater this was fixed. You could try using a scalar function to get the `SpringAvailable` column value instead, or look at upgrading to a newer SQL Server version.

Comment: I can go from SQL 2000 to SQL Express 2005 for free, so that will be the soloution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if your server supports CTEs you could try this one:

```
WITH a as (
SELECT VARENUMMER,
RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(LAGKART.VARENUMMER,CHAR(2),'')))                    AS ItemNo,
RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(LAGKART.SXSON,CHAR(2),'')))                         AS Season, 
ISNULL(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(LAGKART.VARIANT1,CHAR(2),''))),'')           AS Variant1, 
ISNULL(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(LAGKART.VARIANT2,CHAR(2),''))),'')           AS Variant2,
FROM LAGKART
)
select *,
(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[B2BGetSpringFinal] ( a.VARENUMMER, 
                                           a.VARIANT1,
                                           a.VARIANT2
                                        ))                              AS SpringAvailable
from a ;
```

Comment: Thanks Jasen. 
Will give it a try later, and report back.

Comment: I get the following error :

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'

Comment: Add `;` before the `WITH`

Comment: This won't work with SQL 2000 bc it is still passing query result column values as parameters into a table valued function which is not supported until SQL 2005.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (`CROSS` or `OUTER`) to pass column(s) value(s) as arguments to a function:

```
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(LAGKART.VARENUMMER,CHAR(2),'')))  AS ItemNo,
        RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(LAGKART.SXSON,CHAR(2),''))) AS Season, 
        ISNULL(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(LAGKART.VARIANT1,CHAR(2),''))),'') AS Variant1, 
        ISNULL(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(LAGKART.VARIANT2,CHAR(2),''))),'') AS Variant2,
        SpringAvailable.*
FROM LAGKART
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[B2BGetSpringFinal] ( LAGKART.VARENUMMER, LAGKART.VARIANT1,LAGKART.VARIANT2 )
) AS SpringAvailable
```

Comment: Thanks gtqn. Will give it a try later.

Comment: I get the following error :

Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Line 7: Incorrect syntax near 'APPLY'.

Comment: Is is an old SQL version (SQL 2000), so that might explain it.